# How do I retrieve and transfer API data in LoadRunner

Tags: loadrunner

Could someone please help us in this problem that we are having somehow we are not getting it. The GET request is mentioned in the area `Url=/portal/AccountPage/349` Where 349 gets the values for city and phone:

```
web_url("basicinformation.html", 
    "URL=http://atn.dev.loc:2020/portal/resources/views/accountsearch.html", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=http://atn.dev.loc:2020/portal/AccountPage/new/#/", 
    "Snapshot=t8.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    EXTRARES, 
    "Url=/portal/AccountPage/349", 
   "Referer=http://atn.dev.loc:2020/portal/AccountPage/new/#/accountsearch", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);
```

The response for this is:

`"appdata": {"city":"newcity","phone":"3142364236"}`

I want to pass the value for `city` and `phone` each to a variable then enter it in subsequent `POST` requests

Comment: Please read about "Correlation" in the product help (F1 in VuGen)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass the value for "city" and "phone" each to a variable then enter it in subsequent POST requests

Covered in Training Material, Online training material, The tutorial and should be covered by your mentor if nothing else.   The topic is "correlation" and is considered a core foundation tool skill.   In short, you should not be using the tool unless and until you have mastered the skill.